# Can't get ghostscript to install on macOS X

Tags: macos, installation, ghostscript, configure

I've run the ghostscript 9.09 installer several times but even though it does not error out, I'm left with no gs executable anywhere on the system (verified with find / -type l -name gs -print). I'm unsure where/how to troubleshoot this, but I need ghostscript to try out Scribus.  Is anyone aware of a ghostscript incompatibility with macOS X 10.12.6 and what to do about it?  I've tried running the configure script both from Finder and from Terminal and, again, it seems fine. Except I get no results after it goes thru its processes. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Why not compile it from source? Also 9.09 is an older version (current is 9.23)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that we (Artifex) ship an installer for MacOS/X. In fact the only OS for which we ship an installer is Windows.

Where did you get the installer you are using ?

Running configure implies you have picked up source code, not an installer, and simply running configure isn't enough anwyway, you need to run make as well, it isn't clear to me if you've done that. also, IIRC (and I'm not at my desk, I'm travelling) you should run autogen.sh, not configure directly.

Comment: The package manager Homebrew has version 9.23 available.  Run 'brew ghostscript' to install it on your Mac. If you don't have Homebrew installed, install it by typing or pasting: /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"  in the command line.  Homebrew home page is at: https://brew.sh

Answer (score 0):

I used to run Ghostscript on macOS as provided by the [MacPorts project](https://www.macports.org/). I just looked it up on a friend's MacBook: the latest version for macOS 12.6.x (Sierra) available as a MacPorts package is Ghostscript v9.53.3.

It should be quite straightforward to follow the MacPorts instructions to install their framework, and then in Terminal do:

```
sudo port install ghostscript
```

will give you a working Ghostscript installation on your Mac.